# Use object properties without specifying the object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following script is a simple class register script. I don't want to store classes on the global window object, but still I would like to make `new MyClass2();` work. If I would be able to define `obj` variable as global object like the `window` then the following code should work fine.

So every properties on the `obj` object should be available as variable inside the scope of the `defineClass` function.

Is it possible somehow or should I stack with the commented code?

```js
(function() {
  var obj = {};
  window.defineClass = function(className, cb) {
    obj[className] = cb.call(obj /*, obj*/ );
  }
  window.start = function() {
    new obj.MyClass();
  }
})();

defineClass('MyClass', function( /*obj*/ ) {
  function MyClass() {
    this.obj = new MyClass2();
    //this.obj = new obj.MyClass2();
  }

  window.MyClass = MyClass;

  return MyClass;
});

defineClass('MyClass2', function( /*obj*/ ) {
  function MyClass2() {
    console.log('MyClass2');
  }

  return MyClass2;
});

start()
```

Comment: Don't confuse scope with binding. Yes, in js things in global scope are aliased as properties of the global object but the global object is not the global scope. What exactly are you trying to do? Create a new scope that does not pollute the global scope? If so use a closure. Or do you want to minimise pollution of global scope by creating only one variable? If so use an object for namespacing.

Comment: I define my classes like in the example(commented part). But I always has to instance them like new scope.MyClass2(); my life would be much simplier if I could use new MyClass2(); only in my scope without placing all classes to window.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying. You're using the word "scope" to refer to objects which are not scopes. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: When I say object which are not scopes I don't mean your object is not a scope. I mean all objects in javascript are not scopes

Comment: Okay forget about scope. I would like to make my object's properties called 'scope' to be able to used as 'window' properties without writing the object,s name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the notation `new MyClass2()` to work, either define `function MyClass2(){}` in global scope or closure, ex:

```
defineClass('MyClass', function() {
    function MyClass() {
      this.obj = new MyClass2();
    }

    window.MyClass = MyClass;

    return MyClass;

    function MyClass2(){}
});
```

`window` is a special global object as `window.window` is `window` itself.

Using module loader is handy for this kind of problem, ex. [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), [ES6 `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), etc.

Using `iframe` is another possible solution for your need.